# Java heap space error when compiling android project

Tags: java, android, apache-tika

I am trying to add the following jar file:
tika-app-1.1

Here is the Console output:

```
[2012-07-06 22:05:03 - iCards] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator$3) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2012-07-06 22:05:03 - iCards] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator$4) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2012-07-06 22:05:03 - iCards] Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator$5) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
[2012-07-06 22:09:03 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Java heap space
[2012-07-06 22:09:03 - iCards] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Java heap space
```

(This was a very small part of it, it is repeating each time with a different class...

What can I do in order to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options
```

It seems your compiler version is not compatible. That means jar is older version. Try to get latest version of that jar and see.

Comment: The problem is that it is surely the latest version: http://tika.apache.org/download.html

Comment: Then you may downgrade the jar version and check. There is some incompatibility between your compilation level and  jar compilation level.

Comment: When you say downgrade you mean to download an oldest version of the jar?

Comment: I tried to download other versions, but still same problem :(

Comment: Apache Tika builds for Java 1.5 by default, so all the Tika jars have 1.5 classes. Do you need 1.6 or 1.7 classes? If so, you could try downloading the source and tweaking the maven settings then compile

Comment: How can I tweak the maven settings? and then which folders I have to compile? all?

Answer (score 0):

Android dx command requires large stack space. Give '-Xss256m' option to 'java' command. If you are using Eclipse, open eclipse.ini and add '-Xss256m'.

Comment: It's not that. Sometimes it gives this error, sometimes the dx 1 error, it is surely a problem in the jar itself